# Get file to client machine after login using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, remote-access

I have a url which asks for login credentials. After entering correct credentials a .csv file is automatically downloaded to the user machine. I have written a code in asp.net It downloads the file but the file have wrong content it displays some HTML content. I am using this code:

```
 string url = "https://www.abc.com/asdasdxcss/actionlist2.csv";
            string FSourceFilePath = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("temp", "test", "");
            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string respurlpath = "";
            respurlpath = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
            WebRequest request5 = WebRequest.Create(respurlpath);
            request5.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("temp", "test", "");
            HttpWebResponse response5 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            int bytesRead; byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            Server.ScriptTimeout = 30 * 60;
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.BufferOutput = false;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.csv");
            if (response5.ContentLength != -1)
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", response5.ContentLength.ToString());

            while (bytesRead > 0 && Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }



            if (dataStream != null) dataStream.Close();
            Response.End();
```

Content of file downloaded by my code:

```
       <html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/nidp/saml2/sso?id=157&sid=0&option=credential&sid=0"></form>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--
                document.forms[0].submit();
            -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What i expect is:

```
parentID    Action_status   
123           True
```

Comment: What's the html of the file actually downloaded look like? Is it a custom 404 error page or something similar?

Comment: Please post the HTML so we have an idea of what is being downloaded instead.

Comment: see my edit for the output i am getting.

Comment: For what I'm seeing, the link gives you an html form, that is the one that gives you the download of the file. it's like a two step action.
I bet that if you post again for the url in that form, you will get the expected file.

Comment: and how to do that? @PauloCorreia

Comment: You need to get the URL from that form, and use it in another webrequest (atention for the method POST). I suggest you use the HTMLAgilityPack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to help you getting that URL easier.

Comment: i tried it the other way and it gives me "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: even i logged in the url via browser and altered the url with the one i got in html. and it is just sending to landing page of application. Not downloading file.